# How to run a useQuery query in a mutation onSuccess and wait for the result first?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

I'm trying to route the user on login to a page depending on data I get from a useQuery call , but the onSuccess is too quick to run while the query hasn't fetch yet , my code looks like this

```
  const { data, refetch } = useQuery(["tracks"], getTracks, {
    enabled: false,
  });

  const { mutate, isLoading, isError, error } = useMutation(login, {
    onSuccess(d, v, c) {
      Cookies.set("cookieToken", d?.access);

      let type = Cookies.get("cookieToken");
      type = parseJwt(type);
      type = type.user_type;
      refetch();

      if (data) {
        if (type === 5 || type === 6) {
          navigate(`/${data?.object[0]?.id}?type=prio`);
        } else {
          navigate(`/${data?.object[0]?.id}?type=filtering`);
        }
      }
    },
  });
```

I want to onSuccess of the use mutation to fetch  the query  , wait for the result and navigate the user based on the data I get from the query , how to do so  ?

I can't run the useQuery before the onSuccess because it won't succeed without having the token from the mutation

Comment: 1. `const [enabled, setEnabled]` 2. `enabled: enabled` 3. `setEnabled(true)`

Comment: How about not calling `mutate` until the first query is done?

Comment: @Konrad doesn't this also not  guarantee that data would be there when I check the condition?

Comment: @Unmitigated well the query needs to run after user signs in as I need the jwt token for it

Comment: No, it won't be here. It will never be in the `onSuccess` of this mutation no matter how long would you wait. You have to add `onSuccess` to the `useQuery`

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to `await` the `refetch`, so something like this:

```
 const { mutate, isLoading, isError, error } = useMutation(login, {
    onSuccess: async (d, v, c) => {
      Cookies.set("cookieToken", d?.access);

      let type = Cookies.get("cookieToken");
      type = parseJwt(type);
      type = type.user_type;
      await refetch();

      if (data) {
        if (type === 5 || type === 6) {
          navigate(`/${data?.object[0]?.id}?type=prio`);
        } else {
          navigate(`/${data?.object[0]?.id}?type=filtering`);
        }
      }
    },
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using @tanstack/react-query v4+, maybe something like this might help?

```
 const { data, refetch } = useQuery(["tracks"], getTracks, {
    enabled: false,
 });

 const { mutate, isLoading, isError, error } = useMutation(login, {
    onSuccess: async (d, v, c) => {
      Cookies.set("cookieToken", d?.access);

      let type = Cookies.get("cookieToken");
      type = parseJwt(type);
      type = type.user_type;

      // Await until refetch completes and use the data 
      // straight from response instead of "data" from the 
      // "useQuery" hook
      const response = await refetch();

      if (response.data) {
        if (type === 5 || type === 6) {
          navigate(`/${response.data?.object[0]?.id}?type=prio`);
        } else {
          navigate(`/${response.data?.object[0]?.id}?type=filtering`);
        }
      }
    },
  });
```

Please refer to the "refetch" function signature and note that it returns a promise:
https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/reference/useQuery

Comment: this works, because you can't expect `await refetch()` to change the `data` variable in the closure (the result from useQuery). So you have to use the result returned from `refetch()`. If you only need the query to eventually call refetch, I would  use `queryClient.fetchQuery` instead.